# Trying to scale SVG images (ideally dynamically) based on window size

Tags: css, svg, bootstrap-4

I've got a container with two SVG images in it.  I'd like the container, and the images, to have their height determined by a percentage of the viewport (ideally dynamically), within a pre-determined min-height/max-height (and preserving the aspect ratio of the images).

The only answers I've found looking so far haven't exactly fit my requirements, and I'm not even sure from reading if it's possible, and if not, what a reasonable fallback would be.

(I am using django and bootstrap4, if it makes a difference.)

```css
 * { margin: 0px; }
 html, body { height:100%; }
 html { overflow:hidden; }

 #nav-mobile {
   min-height: 24px;
   max-height: 100px;
   height: 20%;
   width: auto !important; 
  }

 .mobile-logo {
    height:100%;
    min-height: 24px;
    max-height: 100px;
    width: auto !important;
 }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar" id="nav-mobile" class="res">
<span class="navbar-item text-left">
    <img src="{% static 'img/one.svg' %}" class="mobile-logo" id="mobile-logo-one" />
</span>
<span class="navbar-item text-right">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="{% static 'img/two.svg' %}" class="mobile-logo" id="mobile-logo-two" />
    </a>
</span>
</nav>
```

I know the code above is miles from working, but I'd like to know if I'm just banging my head against a brick wall. :)

Comment: Did you try     height:100vh

Answer (score 0):

You can use values 100vh; to represent the height of the browser window, and 100vw; to represent the width. It is dynamic and used for many things. If you want to see a live demo, check out my website https://gam3t.in and drag your browser's width to see the navbar dynamically shrink and grow.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a piece of the puzzle I was missing!

Comment: So that works great for the containing <div>.. the svg images don't seem to respect the hint though.. any thoughts?

Comment: I misspoke; I can get the svg images to change dynamically, but not to the correct size.  For example, when I set:`.mobile-logo { vh:15vh;}, in a viewport 860px high, the image (which is originally 400x200), is 410px high.  It's dynamic, but not the size I was looking for..

Comment: @matt so what exactly are you looking for? Do you want them to each be side-by-side and scale to fill the full viewport?